# "tailored towards" or "tailored to"?

Tags: phrases, differences, expressions

Which one would you prefer, in particular in combination with "the needs"?

Google finds a lot more for "tailored to" (30 millions) than for "tailored towards" (only 600 thousands).

Comment: ‘Tailored to’. My second choice would be ‘tailored for’, which gets about 7.7 million hits.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer "tailored to," partially since "tailored towards" implies to me the tailoring may not be complete, but mostly because I find the latter awkward.